# ExpressJS, Sequelize,Postgres DateTime dilemma

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timezone, sequelize.js, luxon

My code is trying to store date-time into the PG database. I have set database timezone to UTC. Here is sequelize model

```
const definition = {
id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    },
 execution_start_datetime: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    execution_end_datetime: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
}
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const table = sequelize.define("foo", definition, {
        "public",
        createdAt: 'created_on',
        updatedAt: 'updated_on',
        freezeTableName: true,
    });
    return table;
};
```

Sequelize configuration looks like

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME,
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        dialectOptions: {
            useUTC: true //for reading from database
        },
        timezone: process.env.DB_TIMEZONE, //to write into the database
        logging: parseInt(process.env.DB_LOGGING) === 1 ? true : false,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        pool: {
            max: parseInt(process.env.DB_POOL_SIZE, 0),
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000
        }
    });
```

I have a problem while a storing and fetching the data. The idea is to always store the data in UTC and fetch in UTC in ISO8601 with out Z at the end (to support multiple timezone users) and browser should render according to the local timezone.
My machine is on IST timezone and postman payload goes as

```
{
  "execution_start_datetime": "2022-11-08T19:23:51",
  "execution_end_datetime": "2022-11-08T19:23:51"
}
```

Here I am not specifying any timezone. Since the express process is also running under IST timezone, either DB or the Node process should automatically convert to UTC. The o/p of above is, the result are coming out when my machine is running on IST and I have set DB_TIMEZONE   ="-5:30"

```
{
  "execution_start_datetime": "2022-11-08T13:53:51.000Z",
  "execution_end_datetime": "2022-11-08T13:53:51.000Z",
  "updated_on": "2022-11-08T12:55:17.689Z",
  "created_on": "2022-11-08T12:55:17.689Z",
}
```

Now I set DB_TIMEZONE   ="UTC" this is the following behaviour (current local time 6:26PM)

```
{
  "execution_start_datetime": "2022-11-08T13:53:51.000Z",
  "execution_end_datetime": "2022-11-08T13:53:51.000Z",
  "updated_on": "2022-11-08T12:56:04.740Z",
  "created_on": "2022-11-08T12:56:04.740Z",
}
```

how and why -5:30 is being considered. Now the funny part, as soon as I add Z at the end this is the following behaviour. DB_TIMEZONE   ="UTC"

```
{
 "execution_start_datetime": "2022-11-08T19:23Z",
 "execution_end_datetime": "2022-11-08T20:23Z"
}
```

and the result is
{

```
"execution_start_datetime": "2022-11-08T19:23:00.000Z",
"execution_end_datetime": "2022-11-08T19:23:00.000Z",
"updated_on": "2022-11-08T12:59:45.518Z",
"created_on": "2022-11-08T12:59:45.518Z",
}
while create_on and updated_on are doing -5:30 the execution_start_datetime and end_datetime are returned as is from the database. what is the impact of Z here.

I am absolutely breaking my head. The idea is to when my browser in UK or in IST, when I select a date and time (probably without timezone), the system should store in UTC. But you may ask me question, UTC by what timezone. Now thats another question, Is it a good practice to pass browser timezone always to backend and backend adds it as an offset (+5:30 or +00:00) to store as UTC.
```

Comment: I didn't find `useUTC` option for PG lib? Where did you find it?

Comment: And `timezone` option is used not for writing dates but for reading them: `The timezone used when converting a date from the database into a JavaScript date. `